# How to add interactive checkbox to existing PDF document with itext?

Tags: java, itext

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("in.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, "out.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
Rectangle position = new Rectangle(36, 760, 144, 790);
//
// how?
//
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

P.S. There is no tables in the PDF

P.P.S. itext 2.1.7

Comment: I hope that you are aware of the fact that iText 2.1.7 should no longer be used: [Can iText 2.1.7 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
RadioCheckField checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "a-name", "Yes");
checkbox.setCheckType(RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK);
checkbox.setChecked(true);
checkbox.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THICK);
checkbox.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
checkbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
stamper.addAnnotation(checkbox.getCheckField(), 1);
```